# Is there a way to reverse a graph in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to reverse the flow of a TensorFlow graph. The reason for this, is that I want to visualize the hidden layers of the graph given a logit vector for the output of the trained graph.

For example, say that I have a fully connected graph given as follows (inspired by MNIST):

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
hidden_w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', [784,100], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer)
hidden_b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', [100], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer)
a1 = tf.matmul(inputs, hidden_w1) + hidden_b1
z1 = tf.nn.relu(a1)

hidden_w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', [100,100], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer)
hidden_b2 = tf.get_variable('b2', [100], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer)
a2 = tf.matmul(z1, hidden_w2) + hidden_b2
z2 = tf.nn.relu(a2)

output_w = tf.get_variable('w3', [100,10], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer)
output_b = tf.get_variable('b3', [10], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer)
a3 = tf.matmul(z2, output_w) + output_b
output = tf.nn.relu(a3)

loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=..., logits=output)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
```

Suppose I now train this graph and want to visualize hidden 1 when only the first output neuron is activated. The way I would do this would be to reverse the flow of the graph and feed a tensor `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` from the output layer back through the reversed graph until I finally got the output of the hidden1 layer. I have tried to see if there is a way to do this in TensorFlow, but there seems to be little information about this. The way I would inutitively construct it is to add an operation sess.run_reverse() when running the graph as follows:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
while training:
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={inputs:...})

# finished training, reverse graph
category_to_visualize = tf.one_hot(indices=0, depth=10)
sess.run_reverse(hidden1, feed_dict={output:category_to_visualize})
```

If this sort of operation doesn't exist or even is possible to get, however, I would instead construct separate operators for reversing the flow of the graph as follows:

```
output_reversed = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1,10])
z3_reversed = tf.nn.relu(output_reversed)
a3_reversed = tf.matrix_inverse(output_w)*(z3_reversed - output_b)

z2_reversed = tf.nn.relu(a3_reversed)
a2_reversed = tf.matrix_inverse(hidden_w2)*(z2_reversed - hidden_b2)

z1_reversed = tf.nn.relu(a2_reversed)
a1_reversed = tf.matrix_inverse(hidden_w1)*(z1_reversed - hidden_b1)
```

I realize that there might be logical flaws to this method that wouldn't make it possible. A couple of things I've overlooked is singular matrices and undefined inversion of ReLu when input is below 0 (ReLu, though, can be replaced by sigmoid for theoretically defined inversion of the entire input space). The core idea, though, is to visualize a feature map given a category - something I believe should be possible if a few assumptions are allowed.

Anyways, please tell me if I'm thinking wrongly here, and if there is a way to reverse the graph!

Answer (score 2):

I think your logic is flawed. Certain operations are unreversable. There are two I see in your program that cannot be undone.

## ReLU

ReLU is a function that turns a negative input into zero, and leaves a positive. Consider the following example.

```
x = np.array([1, 2, -1, -2])
y = np.maximum(x, 0) # Numpy's version of relu
```

This gives us `[1, 2, 0, 0]`. The problem is the negative, i.e., we know that `1` and `2` were `1` and `2`, however, there's no way for us to tell what `0` was (or even should) be. If you were using a leaky ReLU, there would be a solution to this, however it's not very useful because of Matrix Multiplication.

## Matrix Multiplication

The problem with matrix multiplication is that you need to sum the products of columns and rows. For example (not written in python, just matrices):

```
[1, 2]   [ 7,  8,  9]
[3, 4] * [10, 11, 12]
[5, 6]
```

The way you would calculate this would be:

```
[[1], [2]]   [ [7],  8,  9]
[ 3 ,  4 ] * [[10], 11, 12]
[ 5 ,  6 ]
->
[1*7 + 2*10, ?, ?]
[         ?, ?, ?]
[         ?, ?, ?]
```

or

```
[27, ?, ?]
[ ?, ?, ?]
[ ?, ?, ?]
```

We then iterate the columns to get the rest of the values. The problem with this is that we have no idea what was summed up to make `27`, or what their products were, aka, you're trying to solve `27 = ab+cd`. There are literally uncountably infinite ways to solve that. It only gets worse with larger matricies, e.g. you might have to find `27 = ab+cd+ef+gh+kl...+yz`. There is *no way* to calculate that in a way a neural network would find useful.

## Conclusion

A neural network is designed to process and abstract data. In other words, it takes something complicated (a grid of pixels) and makes it simpler (an integer). Doing this backwards doesn't make much sense. Tensorflow, nay, any machine learning library won't do this because it's impossible and not useful.

If you want something that can approximate an input, then I'd advise using a GaNN, or [Generative Adversarial Neural Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network). The basic premise is that you have two neural networks, called the generator and the discriminator. The generator is given a random number and aims to fool the discriminator. The discriminator is given the input dataset and the generator's images and is expected to tell between them.

Comment: Thanks! I already admitted to the ReLu function having an undefined inversion when the input is below 0, though. The matrix multiplication can be solved in a neural network, as we have access to the weights and biases. The equation for forward propagation would be `a = W*x + b`, and its inversion would be `x = W_inv*(a - b)`. This said, though, I take it there is no way to reverse the flow of a graph in TensorFlow, due to some undefined inversions.

Regarding GANs, they don't visualize my graph's fefature maps. I'm looking for ways to visualize my graph's feature maps, given a logits output.

Comment: @AndreasForslöw It's not possible. Imagine an example. We have an input (`I`) of shape `[5, 10]` and weights (`w`) of `[10, 20]`. This matrix multiplies to a shape (`o`) of `[5, 20]`. When calculating, we perform `O[0][0] = I[0][0]*W[0][0] + I[0][1]*W[1][0] + I[0][2]*W[2][0]`. Even if we know what the weights are, we can't reverse the sum (you can't get one answer for each of `x=a+b+c+d+e+f...`). Or, to be more precise, there are an infinite number of answers. It doesn't matter that you have the weights, because _you don't have the inputs_.

Comment: @AndreasForslöw You can make a function to do it, but it's not useful. For example, I could say that `10 = 10 + 0 + 0 + 0...` and then get an input matrix full of zeros. Or I could say that `10 = 2.5 + 2.5 + 2.5 + 2.5` and get an input matrix that is a little more filled in. There's an infinite amount of answers, and you're trying to find one of them that gives useful inputs. We don't know which input gives the right one because it's a neural network. Concerning the logits, I'd recommend attaching the logit onto the inputs (i.e `[pixels, 4, 2...0 0 0 0 1 0 (it's an 8)]`) and then GANNing that.

Comment: @AndreasForslöw However, I think you just want to visualise a plain neural network. You've told your neural network to look at some pixels and decide an output. It may only look at minute details, for example whether there's a line, it might say that's a one. The problem arises when you try is that it only cares about that line. The image might actually just be noise, except you that noise. The NN doesn't care; that's not it's job. In the past people have used derivatives to reform the input and it has always resulted in noise.

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah, you are right! Totally forgot that only (n x n), non-singular matrices are invertible. Anyways, the fully connected network was just an example case; a case that indeed is very reactive to noise. However, today's models (such as capsule networks) tend to be less reactive to noise, which means that their feature maps should be quite consistent even with noise. Thanks for the clarification, anyways!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can visualize activations of your hidden layers, as described in the this paper : http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.06579.pdf

Check the following post for how it is implemented in MNIST dataset

https://medium.com/@awjuliani/visualizing-neural-network-layer-activation-tensorflow-tutorial-d45f8bf7bbc4

Do let me know in the comments if you need any further clarification.